# How to one-hot encode a numpy array consisting of categorical labels?

Tags: python, numpy, encoding, deep-learning, one-hot-encoding

I have a dataset with 7 kinds of lables. I have converted the column as a NumPy array and I want to do one-hot encoding for this column.

```
np.eye(7)[Class_label_paperID]
#Class_label_paperID.shape= 200*1
```

This definetly doesn't work. But how should I proceed from here?

Comment: No idea, but the ```Class_label_paperID``` should have values in the range [0,7), otherwise it will not work.

Answer (score 0):

first of all create a dictionary to connect the single elements of the array with a unique integer.

```py
from collections import defaultdict

data = np.array(['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'three', 'six', 'seven'])
dic = defaultdict(int)
counter = 0
for val in data:
    if not dic[val]: #if its a new entry add it to the dict and increase the counter
        print(val, counter)
        dic[val] = counter
        counter+=1
```

Extract the list of integer:

```py
labels = [dic[x] for x in data]
```

That generates this:

```sh
defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'one': 0, 'two': 1, 'three': 2, 'four': 3, 'five': 4, 'six': 5, 'seven': 6})

[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 5, 6]
```

Use *[tf.utils.to_categorical](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/to_categorical)* to get the one-hot-encoding, this lets you specify the number of classes to use:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(labels, num_classes=7))
```

The output should look like this:

```
[[1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1.]]
```

Hope its helps you with the problem!